# I want to display frametitle+continued but it's showing frametitle+RomanNumbers from second page of a frame while using framebreaks in ppt

Tags: beamer, frame-title, roman-numerals, allowframebreaks

I would like to replace the numbering of `allowframbreaks` frame with continued...,but fail to find out a command for this. For framebreaks I've used the command `\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{frametitle}\end{frame}`. I'm using the following prelims:

```
\documentclass[slidestop,sans,mathserif,compress,10pt]{beamer}
%\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\colorlet{structure}{red!65!black}
%\beamertemplateshadingbackground{green!45}{white!75}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
%\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}{}
%\usepackage{beamerthemePaloAlto}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{slashbox,multirow}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{breqn}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
%\usepackage{cite}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{pgflibraryshapes}

%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{pgflibraryshapes}
\mode<presentation> {
%\usetheme{Marburg}
%\usetheme[hoptionsi]{Berlin}
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
```

Comment: When creating an [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) make sure that it is compilable. Your MWE has at least one error I can see in that the final `{` isn't closed by a matching `}`. Also there is no point including all of the commented out lines since they don't change the result. Idealy your MWE would start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` so that by compiling it we can see exactly the same error you have. That's the best way to get people to help.

Comment: Try including `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second][continued]` in your preamble. Does this do what you want? You can change `continued` to be whatever text you want to appear.

Comment: @Willoughby Thank you very much! Your suggestion has solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Here's how to do it

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{blindtext}   % For filler text
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second][continued]
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{frametitle}
        \blindtext[4]
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The key is the `\setbeamertemplate` command.
This is the general command used to set properties of the template.
The first argument, `frametitle continuation` tells it which property to set.
The second argument, `from second`, is an existing option which puts the same word on all slides after the first.
The third argument, `continued`, is what word that should be, so for example if you wanted 'cont.' instead of 'continued' you could use

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second][cont.]
```

You could also use

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second][\insertcontinuationtext]
```

which inserts the default continuation text, in this case '(cont.)' although it changes with the language.
This is also the default if you leave off the third argument.

See the [beamer user guide](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) creating frames: the frame environment on page 60.